# Android Camera Intent Capture Photo and Resize Photo before Save

Tags: android, image, camera, android-bitmap, android-camera-intent

I'm taking a photo from my native Android Phone Camera! But what I want is to resize the captured photo and THEN save.

What I have been trying is:

```
public void takePhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhotoBox");

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String new_Date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        path = String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "PhotoBox" + "/%s.png", "Product(" + new_Date + ")");

        File photo = new File(path);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        xPath = path;
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }
```

I know after capturing the photo my image is being saved. And I can resize the Image by creating a scaled Bitmap! But in Camera Intent case, what I'm getting is only the Uri for the captured image and then I saved it.

But I want to know

> HOW CAN I RESIZE THE CAPTURED PHOTO FROM ANDROID CAMERA INTENT AND
>   THEN SAVE ?

Comment: what do u mean by resize, any specific ratio? like 720*720 ? what ?

Comment: No. Impossible. With using such Camera intents always the image gets saved first. Use Camera class instead.

Comment: I just need to resize the image in any ratio like 200x200...any

Answer (score 3):

You are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. This requests that the camera app save the image to that location. In your case, you are pointing it to a file, and so the camera app will save the image to that file. It will do that before returning control to you, and so you cannot resize the image before then.

Your choices are:

- Just resize the image afterwards.
- Remove `EXTRA_OUTPUT` from your `Intent`. Then, rather than saving the image to a file, the camera app should give you a thumbnail-sized image via the `"data"` extra in the `Intent` handed to you in `onActivityResult()`. It is possible that this thumbnail does not need to be resized at all; even if it does, you can resize it before you save it somewhere.
- Implement a `ContentProvider` that will receive the image from the camera app, then resize it there before saving it yourself. This is unlikely to work, as you are unlikely to have enough heap space to handle the full-sized image.

Comment: `, rather than saving the image to a file, the camera app should give you a thumbnail-sized image`. It will do both.

Comment: @greenapps: That will depend entirely on the camera app. A well-written camera app will only provide the thumbnail-sized image. Alas, there are hundreds of camera apps pre-installed on thousands of Android device models, and not all of their developers seem to have read the documentation.

Comment: Is it worth to depends on the Intent's "data" and not on the "extra_output"? Because AFAIK both the contents has a huge difference, in terms of resolution and size of the image? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Hemang: You are correct. This is why I noted the thumbnail-sized image in the second bullet and the full-sized image in the third bullet.